# How to Put TextView on top of KeyboardView

Tags: android, custom-keyboard

I am trying to create a custom Android keyboard. I want to put a TextView right on top of KeyboardView.

Here's the XML. On this layout, the TextView displays on the very top of the screen. But I want to put it right on top of the keyboard, regardless the height of the keyboard. I tried playing around with `layout_align*`, but can't seem to do it.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/input_view"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <TextView
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:text="Hello World" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <android.inputmethodservice.KeyboardView
        android:id="@+id/keyboard"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:keyPreviewLayout ="@layout/keyboard_preview"
        />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Here's the screenshot.

[image]

Comment: Hi i am getting a crash when i try to inflate layout with extra elements can you share how you inflate this view inside your service class pls

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `android:layout_above` attribute inside `LinearLayout` as in

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/input_view"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_above="keyboard"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <TextView
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:text="Hello World" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <android.inputmethodservice.KeyboardView
        android:id="@+id/keyboard"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:keyPreviewLayout ="@layout/keyboard_preview"
        />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Such a simple answer. Thanks a lot!

Comment: I did same but I can't get click on any view I added above keyboardview I am using AOSP keyboard as reference